# ng Test throws: TypeError: this.navMenuService.displayAllTabs.subscribe is not a function

Tags: observable, angular-test

when I run ng test I get this error:
TypeError: this.navMenuService.displayAllTabs.subscribe is not a function

navMenuService.displayAllTabs is a public get Observable property

It returns a BehaviorSubject

navMenuService.displayAllTabs.subscribe is called from NavMenuComponent's ngOnInit()

I have tried:

- a fakeNavMenuService,       // same error
- also spyOnProperty          // says there is no 'get'
- also Object.defineProperty  // can't use with Observable, I think

My code:

```
//On the nav-menu.component.spec.ts
fdescribe('NavMenuComponent', () => {
  let component: NavMenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavMenuComponent>;

  let mockNavMenuService: jasmine.SpyObj<NavMenuService>;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    // set up dependencies methods called directly or indirectly from ngOnInit
    mockNavMenuService = jasmine.createSpyObj<NavMenuService>('NavMenuService', ['displayAllTabs']);    
  });
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: NavMenuService, useValue: mockNavMenuService }
  
      ],
      declarations: [NavMenuComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavMenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    (mockNavMenuService.displayAllTabs as unknown as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(false);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


//On the nav-menu.component.ts
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    private _displayAllTabs = false;
    get displayAllTabs(): boolean {
        return this._displayAllTabs;
    }
    constructor(private navMenuService: NavMenuService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {    
        this.navMenuService.displayAllTabs.subscribe((value) => {
            this._displayAllTabs = value;
        });
    }
}


//On the nav-menu.service.ts

export class NavMenuService {
  private _displayAllTabs: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;  

  public get displayAllTabs(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._displayAllTabs;
  }
  public get showAllTabs(): boolean {
    return this._displayAllTabs.getValue();
  }
  public set showAllTabs(value: boolean) {
    if (value === false) {
      this._displayClaimTab.next(value);
    }
    this._displayAllTabs.next(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this:

first I removed these lines from the spec file:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // set up dependencies methods called directly or indirectly from ngOnInit
    mockNavMenuService = jasmine.createSpyObj<NavMenuService>('NavMenuService', ['displayAllTabs']);    
  });
```

AND

```
 (mockNavMenuService.displayAllTabs as unknown as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(false);
```

Then I added this:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    mockNavMenuService = {
      ...jasmine.createSpyObj('mockNavMenuService', ['']),
      displayAllTabs: of()
    } as jasmine.SpyObj<NavMenuService>;
});
```

Cheers